# JavaScript - For loop vs forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6

can someone explain how these two pieces of code achieve the exact same thing* or explain why they may appear to but do not?

```
  for (i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
    xx[i].classList.remove(...y);
  }

  xx.forEach(x => {
    x.classList.remove(...y);
  });
```

Comment: The second is primarily syntactic sugar afaik, and may have a very slight performance difference.

Comment: [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) explained, [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) explained

Comment: `.forEach()` only works with arrays. It will be slightly slower than the counting loop, but well worth the trade off in that `.forEach()` removes the need to manage indexes.

Comment: I think your first one might be better as `for (const i of xx) { i.classList.remove(...y); }`

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a method on the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) prototype. It iterates through each element of an array and passes it to a callback function.

So basically, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a shorthand method for the use-case *"pass each element of an `array` to a `function`"*. Here is a common example where I think [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is quite useful, compared to a `for` loop:

```
// shortcut for document.querySelectorAll
function $$(expr, con) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
}

// hide an element
function hide(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
}

// hide all divs via forEach
$$('div').forEach(hide); 

// hide all divs via for
for (var divs = $$('div'), i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    hide(divs[i])
}
```

As you can see, the readability of the forEach statement is improved compared to a `for` loop.

On the other hand, a `for` statement is more flexible: it does not necessarily involve an array. The performance of a normal `for` loop is slightly better, because there is no function call for each element involved. Despite of this, it is recommended to avoid `for` loops when it can be written as a `forEach` statement.

Answer (score -2):

Careful, if you declare "i" without "var" keyword it will be global.

You can check what forEach can do here:
[forEach MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Very kind, but can't add comment under 50 rep. :)

Comment: That's not a reason to post a bad answer and it won't help you to get to 50 rep. Post good answers that will boost your rep.

Comment: Thanks but In my code I declare ‘i’ just above the for loop using ‘let’.